# Java POI TREND function unsupported

Tags: apache-poi

Trying to evaluate a spreadsheet with function TREND

I am getting this error message

> org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: TREND

So I followed instructions on https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html

But still I am getting the same error.

My current code looks like

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.AggregatingUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.DefaultUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.UDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("my-file.xlsx"));
        String[] functionNames = { "TREND" } ;
        FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new TrendFunction() } ;

        UDFFinder udfs = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;
        UDFFinder udfToolpack = new AggregatingUDFFinder( udfs ) ;

        wb.addToolPack(udfToolpack);
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        formulaEvaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
        formulaEvaluator.evaluateAll();

    }
}
```

The TrendFunction is currently a mock

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NumberEval ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ValueEval ;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction ;

/**
 * A simple function to calculate principal and interest.
 *
 * @author Jon Svede
 *
 */
public class TrendFunction implements FreeRefFunction {

    public ValueEval evaluate( ValueEval[] args, OperationEvaluationContext ec ) {
        System.out.println("in TREND");
        return new NumberEval( 1 ) ;
    }

}
```

Can't see the print in the output.. so obviously it is not being used.

You can download the `xlsx` file from here : https://filebin.ca/3hBZVrUKolfO

The full stack trace I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell Sheet1!B18
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:347)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:220)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:64)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:192)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:267)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAll(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:92)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:27)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: TREND
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.NotImplementedFunction.evaluate(NotImplementedFunction.java:40)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:514)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:278)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: The example you're following is only valid for adding non-built-in User Defined Functions. `TREND` is a standard Excel function. You'll need to write an implementation of it, then contribute that back to Apache POI so it can be baked into the hard-coded list of standard function implementations. See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html for more on how to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Excel Function TREND is supported by ApachePOI from version 4.01 (See [change log](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html))

See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/Trend.html